# Arabic diacritics colors in Chrome Browser disconnected letters

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, diacritics

I am trying to use formatted Arabic text for coloring some letters and diacritics. This works normal as supposed in Firefox. But in Chrome some letters and diacritics are disconnected letters. Is there any solution for this.

Here is the formatted Arabic text.

```
    <b>
 <font size="36">
   <font color="blue">ٱلَّذِينَ يُؤْمِنُونَ بِ<font color="green">ٱ</font>لْغَيْبِ وَيُقِيمُونَ <font color="gray">ٱ</font><font color="orange">ل</font>صَّلَ<font color="pink">و</font><font color="Olive">ٲ</font>ةَ وَمِ<font color="Teal">مّ</span>َا رَزَ<font color="Purple">قْ</font>نَ<font color="Olive">ـٰ</font>هُمْ يُ<font color="Navy">نف</span>ِق<font color="Fuchsia">و</font>نَ</font>
  </font>
</b>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with webkit interpreting words separated by markup. I suggest inserting a zero-width joiner (e.g. using the entity reference ‍) at the beginning and end of the span element content (when you want letters attached):

```css
*{
font-size:36px;
}

.firstpart{
color: red;
}

.secondpart{
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span class="firstpart">وفّ&zwj;</span>&zwj;<span class="secondpart">&zwj;قك الله أخي الفاضل لما يحبّه ويرضاه</span>
```

You can visit [this link](http://www.user.uni-hannover.de/nhtcapri/bidirectional-text.html) to have a deep idea of this problem and similar ones and knowing what problems you may run to with different browsers.